# I deposited a cheque from my sugar daddy and then sent someone money. What do I do now?

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I deposited a cheque from my sugar daddy and then he asked me to send someone money. I only sent a little bit, but then I canceled the transactions before they were completed and my sugar daddy hasn't noticed yet.

What do I do? He emailed me the cheque, then I deposited it through my mobile app. Now I'm freaking out. Please tell me what to do. Can my account get hacked? Can my bank get hacked? Do I call my bank and ask them to cancel the deposit? What do I tell them? Will I get fired from my job if I work for the financial side of the bank? Please help me, I am so scared right now.

Please be kind.

Comment: Never do that again. Your "sugar daddy" is a criminal and is using you to launder money, that he likely stole somewhere, and he is giving to other criminals or funding terrorists. Don't send him or anyone else money on his behalf. In the future, stop accepting free lunches.

Comment: Can cheques be emailed?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo [yes](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/electroniccheck.asp)

Comment: If you work for a bank, you are seriously undertrained.

Comment: Good thing your conscience kicked in, don't get fooled when you know something doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 13):

The cheque is likely to be stolen, forged, drawn on an account with no money, or taken in payment for goods that will never be sent (because they don't even exist).

It will bounce sooner or later.

> Can my account get hacked?

No

> Can my bank get hacked?

No

> Do I call my bank and ask them to cancel the deposit?
> What do I tell them?

Contact the bank and tell them that you suspect the cheque may be fraudulent.  Do not spend any of the money, or send it to anyone else.  The money could be taken back from your account at any time.

> Will I get fired from my job if I work for the financial side of the bank?

Probably not.  But you may get a stern talking to.

Comment: "But you may get a stern talking to." And hopefully some remedial training around scams.

Comment: What do I tell the bank when I call them and tell them that I think the cheque may be fraudulent?? Do I tell them I deposited it through my app?? Do I just ask them to cancel it ? When I tell them I suspect the cheque may be fraudulent will they freeze my assets?

Comment: If I dont tell the bank, I dont send the money anywhere and I dont spend it, will I get penalized when they notice it's a bad cheque, if in fact it is ? What's the best course of action in this sort of circumstance? I have cut off all communication with this person. I am just so scared I cant focus on my work. I really hope you guys can help me.

Comment: @Meoww when you contact your bank, they will need to know which check you suspect is fraudulent. I don't know if they'll care if it was deposited in person, or at an ATM, or via the app, but if they ask, of course just tell them it was in the app. If they ask you why you think it's fraudulent, I think you can be honest. You don't need to say you thought it was a sugar daddy relationship, but you can mention it's someone you met online and you thought they genuinely wanted to give you money. Your account shouldn't be frozen as long as you didn't spend it and have the funds to give back.

Comment: @Meoww Is the bank you deposited the check in also your employer? If yes that might be a little embarrassing, but I'd like to think that this personal problem you have in your bank account wouldn't ever be known by your boss or co-workers, unless someone working on your issue happens to know you... even then, embarrassing, but probably not career ending.

Comment: @Meoww if your bank is also your employer, and you are concerned about losing your job, you may want to contact an employment attorney and ask their advice first.

Comment: I work for a Financial Firm that also has a bank. WhenI started they opened me a bank account to pay me through so I closed my other accounts. I felt off about doing it in the first place and I should have just listened to my gut. I just had a stupid moment of "weakness" and trusted this person but then realized what I had done and now I'm freaking out. I do training on watching for fraudulent activity and everything. I feel so stupid and I'm already so embarrassed. To contact and employment attorney I would just google I'm assuming?

Comment: @Meoww I too once worked for a financial company that was connected with a bank, with my salary paid into a staff account.  The contract and staff handbook were clearly written for bank staff, with some scary stuff.  (For example, letting your account go overdrawn was considered a disciplinary matter that your manager could sanction you for!)  However, I never heard of anything like that happening while I was there; in practice, it was just like any other company.  So in your case, there's at least a chance you won't have to worry about your employment.

Answer (score -3):

A friend of mine received a cheque as a payment and sent it to the bank. Later on the bank said that the cheque was forged or no enough money in it. Unfortunately he already spent the money, and he OWES the same amount of money of the cheque.

So just to be safe, wait for some days until you can withdraw money from the cheque. But I'm pretty sure that's a scam.